# T-SQL - Returning a different value than what is stored in the database for several columns

Tags: t-sql

I have a query that returns 16 columns. 12 of them have similar data (they return values 0, 1 or 2). I want to replace these numbers with letters - 0 with L, 1 with M, and 2 with H.

I can write 12 case statements but that would be overkill and I definitely don't want to do that. I'd much rather convert these values in the front end instead. Is there any way to use something like a function (within the query itself only) which returns the appropriate value?

Please note that I have read only access to the database and there are thousands of databases like these already out there so creating a udf is not possible.

Comment: What is your front end?  You could create an enum that maps a character to each numeric value

Comment: .NET (C#). Yes, I could do that but it would be nice to know if there is some way of dealing with such an issue through T-SQL itself.

Comment: I would just write the case statement.  Copy once then paste it 11 times.  Change 11 column names.  And save the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your front-end, how about using an enum?  You can have enum elements L=0, M=1, H=2. When you pull the (column) data from your DB, cast it to the enum type.  When you display it, you can get the enum name by doing a ToString.
Have a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0h36syw.aspx).

Comment: yup, I will be using an enum if there is no way of doing this in t-sql :)

Answer (score 1):

If you only have read access, you can't create a function, but you could create a common table expression and join to it twelve times...

```
WITH LookupTable (numval, returnletter) as (
    SELECT 0,'L' UNION SELECT 1,'M' UNION SELECT 2,'H')

select LKP1.returnletter as col1,
       LKP2.returnletter as col2
       ...
    from origtable OT
        inner join LookupTable LKP1 on ot.col1 = LKP1.numval
        inner join LookupTable LKP2 on ot.col2 = LKP2.numval
        ....
```

Comment: I did think about using the approach you suggested but the 12 joins was what kept me from using it.

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to use front end processing then.  The benefit of using the CTE is non-existent really with only 3 values.